# mod_rewrite backwards for old dynamic urls

Tags: php, linux, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have mod-rewrite working ok on an apache 2.2, but the problem is that it doesn't work "backwards".

I have these rules that makes SEO friendly urls work:

```
 RewriteRule ^sjg/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$           /showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^sjg/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$      /model.php?model=$1&page=$2      [L]
 RewriteRule ^sjg/([^/]+)/?$                    /model.php?model=$1              [L]
```

But the "old" urls still work i.e. website.com/showimage.php?model=abc&image=123

I would like to rewrite those urls if they are loaded directly or from old links in order to have only one url-scheme working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a page to report errors, 404 in particular, you can add this rule at the end  and you should be fine:

`RewriteRule ^.*$ __404_PAGE_HERE__`

This will redirect all requests that didn't match your previous rules to your 404 page.

Best wishes.

Comment: but my goal is that if someone loads the old urls, they do get the page but from the "new" url.

Comment: Oh pardon me. Well what comes at the top of my mind is to check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and after a few validations you should be able to determine the redirect link I suppose. @Jesper

Comment: OK Thanks, I guess I can code my way out of it, I was thinking of a .htaccess / mod_rewrite solution, but I have just done it with PHP instead (as you suggest) :)